# Subdomains and accessing common files on main domain

Tags: php, subdomain

Where my domain is for example `mywebsite.com`, I have a some directories I keep common assets such as `mywebsite.com/css` or `mywebsite.com/tools`.

When I create subdomain sites here `mywebsite.com/sites/mysubdomain1/`, where the sub domain would be mapped `http://mysubdomain1.com`, I'm having issues including the files from the main domain.

Currently when visiting `http://mysubdomain1.com` all the includes are breaking, as it is treating `mysubdomain1` as the server root, not `mywebsite`.

After some research, symlinks come up as an option, but it seems to me that this is a way to point elsewhere on the server like a shortcut, which is not what I'm after. Is this something better suited to .htaccess? I couldn't find (or at least understand how to implement) an example that solved this seemingly basic issue.

I'd also like this to work as I develop on localhost, which is why I'm not just going with absolute urls.

How could I get this to work? Thanks

Comment: Are the files loaded at the client (css, js), or server (php scripts)?

Comment: Having issues with client for sure - let me confirm php

Comment: @RPM looks like it is just client afterall. I have a bunch of stuff passing from php to js which stopped working - should have known better.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely would use the symbolic link method.  If you could get that working it would be the quickest, easiest and best option: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html

Other alternatives:

- Save the absolute path in a var or php.ini so that you can have a different one for production and local host
- If you really wanted to take the time, you could use some type of php routing engine and code to serve files from a different path... I'm sure it could work but I think it would take a lot of effort.